# Error with Ember.js + Rails - undefined 'Ember.Router.extend'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I tried zillion tutorials about Rails backend and Ember.js and each time I'm getting an error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Ember.Router.extend')
```

Does anyone have working code with Rails 3.2 and ember-rails gem which shows correct routing?

p.s. I've got this error even with default routing generated by ember-rails command:

```
rails g ember:bootstrap
```

p.s.2. Yes, I've got jQuery - other functions work properly, only Ember.Router not.

Comment: Is it related only to Ember.Router, or is Ember itself undefined ?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't gotten very far in programming your app try giving these scripts a try:

run `rails new app_name -m http://emberjs.com/template.rb`

Add `config.ember.variant = :development` into config/application.rb

run `rails g ember:install --head`

Now you should a have a working rails app with ember and ember-data included and embers MVC structure under assets/javascripts.

Cheers!

P.s. Don't forget to download handlebars and update the store.js file to the most current revision (10 as of this post)

Also, go for coffeescript. It's much more readable unless you're a diehard braces fan.

Comment: Thanks Luke. I'm using some demo code from Github which contains Ember.js and Handlebars outside the gem. I think it's something similiar to your solution (maybe the same). Anyway Router works like a charm. I've got another problem with "valueBinding", but it's topic for another post. If I won't find answer I'll back here.